# Adding a new entity updates database automatically, without calling SaveChanges

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

```
var po = context.Posts.Find(1);
po.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Added Later" });
```

Can someone explain why this is saved to database when I'm not calling `SaveChanges()`?

Thought I need to call `SaveChanges` every time I changed something. Or is it because its in my seed function? Because in controllers I need to call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. How is your DbContext initialized? Can you expand your code a little more?

Comment: The calls from the **`Seed`** function will be automatically committed by the EF runtime - it will call  `SaveChanges()` for you. In your own code, you're right - you always have to call `SaveChanges()` to commit your changes and additions to the actual database